# WebSphere Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) over ssh

Tags: bash, ansible, websphere

I am running 9.0.0.11 WebSphere. To install a war file I go through GUI installer and on the last stage press `View administrative scripting command for last action` to see the command line syntax that I can use in my ansible-playbook.

I also need to set `WebSphere Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)` option in my app. How to do it over ssh or in ansible-playbook?

Answer (score 0):

See IBM KnowledgeCenter topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/txml_classloader.html for wsadmin scripting commands to "Modifying class loader modes for applications using wsadmin scripting"